# TreeSet of String Illogical for me behaviour

Tags: java, tree, set

I have this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    NavigableSet<String> myset = new TreeSet<String>();
    myset.add("a");
    myset.add("aa");
    myset.add("b");
    myset.add("bb");
    myset.add("c");
    myset.add("cc");

    System.out.println(myset.ceiling("a"));
    System.out.println(myset.floor("aaa"));
    System.out.println(myset.higher("a"));
    System.out.println(myset.lower("bb"));
}
```

I thought that it would print : `a,b,null,c`. Because for example `higher("a")` should give `null`, because a is the root of this tree, but instead it gives `aa`. The definition of `higher` is `Returns the least element in this set strictly greater than the given element, or null if there is no such element.` So strictly greater means greater than `a`, but since `a` is the root of the three , there is nothing greater than it. `aa` is after `a` in the alphabetical ordering.

Actually it returns the exact oposite of what I want. Why is that. This seems quite illogical to me. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because for example higher("a") should give null, because a is the root of this tree, but instead it gives aa.

Which element is the root of the tree doesn't matter, but if the tree is balanced and it should be the mid value e.g. '"bb"' should be the root.

"aa" is the first after "a" as the String starts with the same character but it's longer, so this is the expected result.

> since a is the root of the three , there is nothing greater than it.

`"a"` is the *smallest* so nothing is less than it.

> it returns the exact oposite of what I want.

In numbers we count from 0, 1, 2, 3 etc increasing from left to right.

In the alphabet we say a, b, c, d increasing from left to right. i.e. a < b && a < c

Where it gets confusing is that comparison is [ASCIIbetical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asciibetical+order) In otherwords the order of the ASCII codes of the letters matters. (More specifically, the codes used when encoded as UTF-16)  This means that '0' < '9' and '9' < 'A' and 'A' < 'Z' but 'Z' < 'a' and 'a' < 'z'

[image]